# C++ Not printing duplicate numbers to the output

Tags: c++

I have to read in a .txt file that contains votes used to determine who would win a pretend election. Here is a little bit of the file so you can get an understanding.

```
1YYYYYYYYYYThe New Guy
2YNYNYNYNYNHarry Potter
2YNNYYNNYYNHarry Potter
2NNNNNNNNNNThe New Guy
3NYNYNYNYNYThe New Guy
3YYYYYYYYYYHarry Potter
3YYYYYYYYNYHarry Potter
```

The first number is the "ID" number and if their are any duplicates of that number I am not supposed to read it into the output.The list of number goes all the way up to 99 with duplicates scattered throughout the file as shown. The numbers are all in order though. So it can go 1222333 as shown but cant do 122332. Here is the code I have so far, the loop just stops when it hits the first duplicate, any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
int main()
{
int ID; //pirate ID number
int IDTest;
char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6, ch7, ch8, ch9, ch10; //vote on amendments
std::string vote; //vote for captain
std::ifstream fileReader; //open file for reading
fileReader.open("BallotsHogwart.txt");
if (fileReader.fail())
{
   std::cout << "The ballots failed to open with code: " << fileReader.failbit;
}
else
{
    do
    {
        IDTest = ID;
        fileReader >> ID;
        if (IDTest != ID)
        {
            std::cout << "Id:" << ID;
            fileReader >> ch1;
            fileReader >> ch2;
            fileReader >> ch3;
            fileReader >> ch4;
            fileReader >> ch5;
            fileReader >> ch6;
            fileReader >> ch7;
            fileReader >> ch8;
            fileReader >> ch9;
            fileReader >> ch10;
            std::cout << " char 1 - 10: " << ch1 << ch2 <<  ch3 << ch4 << ch5 << ch6 << ch7 << ch8 << ch9 << ch10;
            getline(fileReader,vote);
            std::cout << " the votee: " << vote << std::endl;
        }
    } while(!fileReader.eof());
}
fileReader.close();
return 0;
```

}

Comment: Will you ever have duplicates out of order?  ie 1,2,3,1,2,3,3,2,1?

Comment: No, the numbers are all in order

Comment: So, I don't see a question here. With what do you want help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to ignore the line when the ID is duplicated using getline()

The code will be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <limits>
#include <cstdio>
#include <string>
int main() {
    int ID = 0; //pirate ID number
    int IDTest;
    char ch1, ch2, ch3, ch4, ch5, ch6, ch7, ch8, ch9, ch10; //vote on amendments
    std::string vote; //vote for captain
    std::string ignore; //ignore
    std::ifstream fileReader; //open file for reading
    fileReader.open("asdas.txt");
    if (fileReader.fail())
    {
        std::cout << "The ballots failed to open with code: " << fileReader.failbit;
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            IDTest = ID;
            fileReader >> ID;
            if (IDTest != ID)
            {
                std::cout << "Id:" << ID;
                fileReader >> ch1;
                fileReader >> ch2;
                fileReader >> ch3;
                fileReader >> ch4;
                fileReader >> ch5;
                fileReader >> ch6;
                fileReader >> ch7;
                fileReader >> ch8;
                fileReader >> ch9;
                fileReader >> ch10;
                std::cout << " char 1 - 10: " << ch1 << ch2 << ch3 << ch4 << ch5 << ch6 << ch7 << ch8 << ch9 << ch10;
                getline(fileReader, vote);
                std::cout << " the votee: " << vote << std::endl;
            }
            else {
                getline(fileReader, ignore);
            }
        } while (!fileReader.eof());
    }
    fileReader.close();
    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!, I tired using filereader.ignore towards the beginning and I guess I just had the loop in the wrong order. This solved my problem though. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a `map`

```
std::ifstream fileReader; //open file for reading
fileReader.open("BallotsHogwart.txt");
if (fileReader.fail())
{
    std::cout << "The ballots failed to open with code: " << fileReader.failbit;
}
else
{
    string line;
    std::map<string, string> myvotes;
    do 
    {
        getline(filereader, line);
        // pull out ID
        std::map<string,string>::iterator value = myvotes.find(ID); 
        if (value == myvotes.end())
           continue;
        // do the rest of your processing on line.
        // put "Harry Potter" in map.
        myvotes.insert(ID, candidate);

    } while(!fileReader.eof());

    fileReader.close();
    return 0;
}
```